# How do i make a button display a permanent image on right click in python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, minesweeper

This is my first time using tkinter, and I'm trying to make a minesweeper game in python. I found the method for adding an event on right-click but I'm struggling with actually doing what i need to do. Here is the relevant code:

```
def _config_buttons(self):                
        self.reverseboardGUI={v: k for k, v in self.boardGUI.items()}
        for button in self.boardGUI.values():
            button.config(
                command = lambda button=button:self._openfield(button))
            button.bind("<Button-2>",lambda button=button:
                        self._right_click(button))
           
          **button.bind("<Button-3>",lambda button=button:
                        self._right_click(button))**
```

and the function that is supposed to set the flag on the right clicked field:

```
def _right_click(self,button):
        self.root.img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("Images/flag.jpg")
                                           .resize((25,25)))
        button.configure(image = self.root.img)
        button.image = self.root.img
```

Im getting the error: *'Event' object has no attribute 'configure'*  and no matter how i try to change the args to the functions and the parameters passed I can't get it to work.
I can include the full code if needed  too.

Comment: Instead of `.bind(..., lambda button=button: ...` use `.bind(..., lambda event, button=button: ...`. When tkinter is calling a function from an event, it passes in an event parameter. Your `lambda` doesn't account for that.

Comment: That solves it, thank you!